# git checkout tag, git pull fails in branch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout

I have cloned a git repository and then checked out a tag:

```
# git checkout 2.4.33 -b my_branch
```

This is OK, but when I try to run `git pull` in my branch, git spits out this error:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
>   details
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so
>   with:
>
> ```
> git branch --set-upstream new origin/<branch>
> ```

I want `git pull` to only update the master branch and leave my current branch alone (it's a tag anyway). Is something like this possible?

The reason I need this is that I have a automatic script which always git pulls the repository and of course fails because of the error above..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull: There is no tracking information for the current branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056324/git-pull-there-is-no-tracking-information-for-the-current-branch)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Edit:** For newer versions of Git, `--set-upstream master` has been deprecated, you should use `--set-upstream-to` instead:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

---

As it prompted, you can just run:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

After that, you can simply run `git pull` to update your code.

Comment: This solved the problem. But I still have to understand how my master branch lost the reference to origin. I was on a branch and did `git checkout master`. I couldn't do `git pull` because the reference to origin was lost. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: 'git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master my_branch' worked for me

Comment: I am trying to work on a branch, I have cloned a repo, and checked out a branch, so WHY would I want to set --set-upstream-to=origin/master.   Is this going to push my changes there?  Why would I not set it to the BRANCH I am working on?

Answer (score 92):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this command:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

From the help file the -u basically sets the default for pulls:

```
-u, --set-upstream`

  For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add 
  upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and
  other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge in 
  git-config(1).
```

Answer (score 48):

Try these commands:

```
git pull origin master
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 11):

Switch back to the master branch using

```
$ git checkout master
```

and then run the `git pull` operation

```
$ git pull origin/master
```

Afterwards, you can switch back to your `my_branch` again.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I wanted to know if there is a "official" way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

[@alesko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10147475/2098832) : it is not possible to only do only `git pull` after checkout `my_branch` to update `master` branch only.
Because `git pull` will also merge to the **current** branch -> in your scenario to the `my_branch`

[@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14232729/2098832): that will do also the push. why is that?

```
$ git branch -u origin/master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

and acording to docs:

```
-u <upstream>
  Set up <branchname>'s tracking information so <upstream> is considered  
  <branchname>'s upstream branch. If no <branchname> is specified,  
  then it defaults to the current branch.
```

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you are on the right branch.
Then (one time only):

```
git branch --track
```

After that this works again:

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 4):

You might have multiple branch. And your current branch didn't set its upstream in remote.

Steps to fix this:

```
git checkout branch_name
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/remote_branch_name local_branch_name
```

e.g.

```
// this set upstream of local branch develop to remote branch  origin/develop,
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop develop
```

After doing this, when you do `git pull`, it pull from specified branch.

Answer (score 4):

You could specify what branch you want to pull:

```
git pull origin master
```

Or you could set it up so that your local master branch tracks github master branch as an upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git pull
```

This branch tracking is set up for you automatically when you clone a repository (for the default branch only), but if you add a remote to an existing repository you have to set up the tracking yourself. Thankfully, the advice given by git makes that pretty easy to remember how to do.

--set-upstream is deprecated in git 1.9.x, apparently. 
Going forward you'd want to use something like

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

assuming you've checked out master already. If not, 
`git branch -u origin/master master` will work

Answer (score 3):

If like me you need to do this all the time, you can set up an alias to do it automatically by adding the following to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    set-upstream = !git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`
```

When you see the message `There is no tracking information...`, just run `git set-upstream`, then `git push` again.

Thanks to https://zarino.co.uk/post/git-set-upstream/

Comment: I used this to add it globally: `git config --global alias.set-upstream '!git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/\`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD\`'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
git checkout master

git pull origin master
```

Comment: This is not really answering the question. Also although there's no accepted answer the top voted one is much more fitting as an answer to this old question

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your tracking (upstream) for the current branch

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Is already deprecated instead of that you can use --track flag

```
git branch --track master origin/master
```

I also like the doc reference that @casey notice:

```
-u <upstream>
  Set up <branchname>'s tracking information so <upstream> is considered  
  <branchname>'s upstream branch. If no <branchname> is specified,  
  then it defaults to the current branch.
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin master
When I did a pull again I only got the updates from master and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

In order to just download updates:

```
git fetch origin master
```

However, this just updates a reference called `origin/master`. The best way to update your local `master` would be the checkout/merge mentioned in another comment. **If** you can guarantee that your local `master` has not diverged from the main trunk that `origin/master` is on, you *could* use `git update-ref` to map your current `master` to the new point, but that's probably not the best solution to be using on a regular basis...

Answer (score 0):

This command is deprecated: `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`

So, when trying to set up tracking, this is the command that worked for me:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```