# Git pull - default remote and branch using -u option - works with push but not pull

Tags: git, github

I am on Git version 2.6.3, and get this message when just running

```
git pull
```

> "There is no tracking information for the current branch."

I was under the impression that git would default to origin and the branch with the same name under the "simple" config.

After some trouble, I discover that the easiest way to configure this is to use the -u option like so:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

then it will say:

> "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin."

so my question is, why can't we use the -u option with git pull?

```
$ git pull -u origin master
```

the `-u` option is not recognized on pull, only with push

my question is - is there a good reason for that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056324/

Comment: thanks, that question is basically the same, but I was hoping for a better answer than the one given there

Comment: @starlocke I updated my question. It's better to use the -u option, but the -u option only works with git push not git pull, and I am wondering why. Also, it's probably important to upgrade Git to version > 2.0

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to set the upstream of your current branch
$ `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`

This way your setting the upstream branch to master by default when pulling and pushing without actually using a `push` or `pull` command.

Now try to `git pull` and it should start gathering everything from your repository and after that it will say it's `Already up-to-date`

If you have any further questions, I'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 4):

`-u`is just a shortcut for using `--set-upstream`. This flag will cause your local branch to track your remote branch from remote upstream. You only need to do this action once and ideally at the begining by using `git push -u origin <branch_name>`.

This means that when you use `git pull`, `git fetch` and `git push` it should assume that your local branch and the remote branching that is tracking will sync.

If you want to know read more go here: [An Asymmetry Between Git Pull and Git Push](http://longair.net/blog/2011/02/27/an-asymmetry-between-git-pull-and-git-push/)

Answer (score 3):

> the `-u` option is not recognized on pull, only with push

> my question is - is there a good reason for that?

Well... actually Git 2.24 (Q4 2019, 4 years later) will provide `-u` for `git pull`/`git fetch`!

Official reason:

> "`git fetch`" learned "`--set-upstream`" option to help those who first
> clone from their private fork they intend to push to, add the true
> upstream via "`git remote add`" and then "`git fetch`" from it.

You can follow along [the discussions here](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq7ebshz7v.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/).

See [commit 24bc1a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24bc1a129260eaf713c87f087f28883fe18891b5) (19 Aug 2019) by [Corentin BOMPARD (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9437394](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94373946614f864bdcd5e0cb72e360edbed1c77f), 09 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `pull`, `fetch`: add `--set-upstream` option

> Add the `--set-upstream` option to `git pull`/`fetch` which lets the user set the upstream configuration (`branch.<current-branch-name>.merge` and `branch.<current-branch-name>.remote`) for the current branch.
>
> A typical use-case is:
>
> ```
> git clone http://example.com/my-public-fork
> ```
>
> git remote add main http://example.com/project-main-repo
> git pull --set-upstream main master
>
> or, instead of the last line:
>
> ```
> git fetch --set-upstream main master
> ```
>
> git merge # or git rebase
>
> This is mostly equivalent to cloning project-main-repo (which sets upsteam) and then "git remote add" my-public-fork, but may feel more natural for people using a hosting system which allows forking from the web UI.
>
> This functionality is analog to "`git push --set-upstream`".

---

Note: that last feature introduced a type, fixed with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

See [commit 391c7e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/391c7e40b516a0e9e7817083e0966805acffbdf3) (31 Oct 2019) by [Ralf Thielow (`ralfth`)](https://github.com/ralfth).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7ab2088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ab2088255449e6336167295c4bc3e4a60126b41), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`fetch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/391c7e40b516a0e9e7817083e0966805acffbdf3): fix typo in a warning message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ralf Thielow</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>

So it is not:

```
multiple branch detected, incompatible with --set-upstream
```

But:

```
multiple branches detected, incompatible with --set-upstream
```

---

Note: With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the documentation has been updated.

See [commit 9c68873](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c688735f68ef76237708db66b2078bbe78d8f09) (09 Mar 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ab8ef92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab8ef920277a12ffacae2ae9d55b317fa0a42796), 25 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pull`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c688735f68ef76237708db66b2078bbe78d8f09): document more passthru options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) accepts the options `--dry-run`, `-p`/`--prune`, `--refmap`, and `-t`/`--tags` since [a32975f516](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a32975f516f2077928e29729e29612bd055c24ab) ("`pull`: pass git-fetch's options to [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)", 2015-06-18, Git v2.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f02274e4c4506b923b510a24da7991656f4db14) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)), `-j`/`--jobs` since [62104ba14a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62104ba14af4845c6c1ba1dab05fad4a289d806f) (submodules: allow parallel fetching, add tests and documentation, 2015-12-15, Git v2.8.0-rc0), and `--set-upstream` since [24bc1a1292](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24bc1a129260eaf713c87f087f28883fe18891b5) (pull, fetch: [`git add --set-upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) option, 2019-08-19, Git v2.24.0-rc0). Update its documentation to match.

---

Note: With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the `--set-upstream` option is clearer:

See [commit 847b372](https://github.com/git/git/commit/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a) (12 Aug 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ee356a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee356a8818b1dd164ffd1936afbafba52608536b), 19 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`fetch, pull doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a): correct description of '`--set-upstream`'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> The '`--set-upstream`' option to [`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> (which is also accepted by [`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/git-pull.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> and passed through to the underlying [`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>) allows setting the upstream configuration for the current branch.
>
> This was added in [24bc1a1292](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24bc1a129260eaf713c87f087f28883fe18891b5) (`pull`, `fetch`: add  `--set-upstream` option, 2019-08-19, Git v2.24.0-rc0).
>
> However, the documentation for that option describes its action as 'If the remote is fetched successfully, pull and add upstream (tracking) reference [...]', which is wrong because this option does not cause neither `git fetch` nor `git pull` to pull:
>
> - [`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> does not pull and
> - [`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/git-pull.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> always pulls.
>
> Fix the description of that option.
> If the remote is fetched successfully, add upstream

The [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/847b37271ed607d459fbe0f60a6dea937787390a/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L188-L191) now includes:

> If the remote is fetched successfully, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less `git pull` and other commands.

It removes the notion of pulling and then adding upstream.

Comment: thank god, it was dumb not to have this feature (I guess)