# Cannot git pull in a new branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull

I'm working on a new branch created by a colleague. I have committed all the changes and when I try to `git pull`, it gives me an error:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> kiet_tnp
$
```

What do I do? Without `git pull`, I cannot push my codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pull: There is no tracking information for the current branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056324/git-pull-there-is-no-tracking-information-for-the-current-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like git is hinting, do:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/kiet_tnp kiet_tnp
git pull
```

assuming your colleague has created kiet_tnp branch that he's/she's asking you to pull.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you :)

Comment: Once you receive a few answers, feel free to close out your question by accepting any answer as accepted