# git join existing project

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to use git/bitbucket for a new project that already exists. I proceeded as follows (under Windows if that matters):

- create a new folder
- open with Git Bash
- git init
- git clone "repository here, from bitbucket.org"
- git pull

I get the error:
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

So from my understanding, I should be able to pull the existing repository to my local disk, make changes to the files, and then push the changes to git. Could someone tell me which commands are needed to achieve this? The only branch we have is: master, tagged with "main" and "development". This is not a big project, but we want to use git for version control.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no tracking information for the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056324/there-is-no-tracking-information-for-the-current-branch)

Comment: Skip `git init`, and just do `git clone <address> <dir>`. `<dir>` is optional, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cloning the repository, follow below sequences:

1. git fetch origin
2. git pull branch_name (There are many different options to take update from the origin)
3. Update the file
4. git add file_name
5. git commit -m "commit message"
6. git push origin branch_name

Now, all the changes which you made, finally pushed to the remote repository.