# Error when pushing to remote master branch on GitHub from VSCode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I attempt to push my latest code to the master branch on Github using VSCode I get a pop-up error message advising the following:

> Can't push refs to remote. Try running 'Pull' first to integrate your
>   changes.

So I try a Pull, but I get a pop-up window advising me:

> There is no tracking information for that branch.

Here's the Git log for the Push:

```
> git push origin master
To https://github.com/WebDevelopWolf/Date-A-Dog.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/WebDevelopWolf/Date-A-Dog.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And the Git Log for the 'Pull':

```
> git pull --tags
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

I can see it's asking about merging - however I only have the one branch and that's the original master branch. There is a fair bit of code in there, but the last thing that was committed was a README.md file and I did that from GitHub itself, so I don't know if that makes a difference at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no tracking information for the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056324/there-is-no-tracking-information-for-the-current-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+There+is+no+tracking+information+for+the+current+branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local branch is behind the remote branch you care about, so you need to pull those changes (preferably with `--rebase` in this case).

However, `git pull` by default pulls from a *tracked* branch. The branch in question is not tracking anything.

So, follow the error message’s instructions and use `git branch --set-upstream...`, then `git pull`, then try `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

Do below sequence

1. Git pull origin master
2. resolve any merge conflicts if any
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "....."
5. git push